# How to change a value within a list of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I essentially have two questions, both are related.

1) How do I change a value within a list of lists (I provided a example problem)?

2) Why does my code not work?

I have a list which was created from the Tally function on a text file.  The result is shown below...

```
tally = {{"tree", 5}, {"State", 6}, {"swimming", 3}, {"began", 
2}, {"season", 8}, {"Force", 2}, {"Sooners", 10}, {"three", 
4}, {"second", 14}, {"medley", 6}, {"relay", 17}, {"junior", 
5}, {"sophomore", 3}, {"freshman", 5}, {"coach", 2}, {"Pratt", 
2}, {"think", 2}, {"close", 2}, {"thought", 2}, {"events", 
8}, {"finished", 9}, {"individual", 4}, {"collected", 
4}, {"honors", 4}, {"along", 2}, {"third", 13}, {"showing", 
4}, {"swept", 2}, {"first", 5}, {"Junior", 2}, {"star", 
22}, {"freestyle", 4}, {"runner", 2}, {"Sooner", 2}, {"scored", 
2}, {"respectively", 2}, {"finishes", 4}, {"Sophomore", 
2}, {"opening", 3}, {"finish", 2}, {"lifetime", 2}, {"times", 
2}, {"posted", 3}, {"marks", 2}, {"Championships", 
3}, {"conference", 2}, {"recorded", 2}, {"vital", 2}, {"relays", 
4}, {"school", 3}, {"records", 2}, {"earned", 3}, {"fourth", 
3}, {"campaign", 2}, {"against", 5}, {"Northern", 6}, {"Colorado",
 5}, {"helped", 2}, {"Arizona", 2}, {"Idaho", 2}, {"named", 
2}, {"Academic", 2}, {"backstroke", 2}, {"fifth", 3}, {"regular", 
2}, {"winning", 2}, {"victorious", 2}, {"sixth", 2}, {"RioRancho",
 4}, {"School", 2}};
```

I want to be able to find the string "star" within the list and change the associated number with that string to 1000.  I tried using the following code:

```
tally /. _?Last@(First@# == "star" &) -> 1000
```

It does not work the way I want.  The number value associated with "star" remains unchanged.  I know there is a way to do this.  I just can't see it...

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Why not just `tally /. {"star", _} -> {"star", 1000}` ?

Comment: The `First` part of your pattern works alright, but you can't take the `Last` of that. It doesn't mean that the last part of your matching is replaced by 1000.

Comment: Simon gave you the solution.  Why your version doesn't work is twofold: 1. `?` must be followed by a function.  `First@# == "star" &` is a function but `(Last@(First@# == "star" &))` is not 2. you are replacing the whole thing that `_ ? ...` matches not just the second part of that subexpression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are another 3 options:

```
If[#[[1]] == "star", {"star", 1000}, #] & /@ tally
```

But this is a terrible option, I just wrote for pedagogical reasons. Let's see another one:

```
Replace[tallyBig, {"star", _} -> {"star", 1000}, 1];
```

This is better, due too level specification, I believe MMA does't waste time looking where it's not necessary. Now the quickest that I get was:

```
ReplacePart[tallyBig,Position[tallyBig[[All,1]],"star",1]->{"star",1000}]
```

Let's compare performance:

```
tallyBig = RandomChoice[tally, 1*^6]

(*Murta1*)   If[#[[1]]=="star",{"star",1000},#]&/@tallyBig;//AbsoluteTiming
(*Szabolcs*) tallyBig/.{"star",_}->{"star",1000};//AbsoluteTiming
(*Murta2*)   Replace[tallyBig,{"star",_}->{"star",1000},1];//AbsoluteTiming
(*Stefan*)   Scan[(tallyBig[[#,2]]=1000)&,Position[tallyBig,"star",{2}][[All,1]]];//AbsoluteTiming
(*Murta3*)   ReplacePart[tallyBig,Position[tallyBig[[All,1]],"star",1]->{"star",1000}];//AbsoluteTiming

{1.294130, Null}
{0.843827, Null}
{0.141805, Null}
{0.133081, Null}
{0.092666, Null}
```

Now Murta3 is the best option and Murta2 and Stefan gets almost the same result.

Comment: +1 for options, timings, and a fast method.  BTW, `tallyBig = RandomChoice[tally, 1*^5];` might be a better test list.

Comment: Tks! I agree, `tallyBig` updated. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for a further analysis of my question.  This will be good for a much larger data evaluation and analysis, which is coming soon for me!

Comment: I'm glad to help. Thank you for choosing my answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could also try to get the positions of your string

```
pos = Position[tally, "star", {2}][[All, 1]]
```

and then you could use these positions to replace the value.

```
Scan[(tally[[#, 2]] = 1000) &, pos]
```

The variable `tally` is directly modified.

Comment: Nice `Scan` and `Position` combination. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replacement

```
tally /. {"star", _} -> {"star", 1000}
```

Why your version doesn't work is twofold:

1. `?` must be followed by a function. `First@# == "star" &`is a function but `(Last@(First@# == "star" &))` is not
2. you are replacing the whole thing that `_ ? ...` matches not just the second part of that subexpression.

Answer (score 0):

This answer shows how to define functions that do what is requested.

The first two solutions generate a brand new list. They do not modify the list in place. The third solution modifies the list in place.

#### Solution 1

```
replaceViaCopy[lis_, key_, rep_] := 
  ReplacePart[lis, {Position[lis, {key, _}][[1, 1]], 2} -> rep];

test = {{"tree", 5}, {"State", 3000}, {"swimming", 
   3}, {"began", 2}, {"season", 8}, {"Force", 2}, {"Sooners", 
   10}}

replaceViaCopy[test, "State", 6000]
```

returns

```
{{"tree", 5}, {"State", 6000}, {"swimming", 3}, {"began", 
  2}, {"season", 8}, {"Force", 2}, {"Sooners", 10}}
```

#### Solution 2

This definition is clearer and shorter.

```
replaceViaCopy2[lis_, key_, rep_] := lis /. {key, _} -> {key, rep}
```

#### Solution 3

To change the list without creating a new copy

```
SetAttributes[replaceInPlace, HoldFirst];

replaceInPlace[lis_, key_, rep_] := 
         (lis[[Position[lis, {key, _}][[1, 1]], 2]] = rep;)
```

Then

```
replaceViaCopy[test, "State", 6000]
```

will not return anything, but will modify `test`.